# Cannot hide Mapview in a fragment when resumed from another Activity

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I create a Mapview programmatically in a fragment(it is not a `MapFragment`), and I called the the `Mapview'`s method like `onResume()`, `onPause()` in appropriate places.

I can hide the `MapView` by calling `mv.setVisibility(View.Gone)` normally when I stay in this fragment.

When I press HOME or navigate to another activity, after resumed, the `Mapview` can never be set to gone and it stays there as a front view which covered all my views that should be above it.

What is the problem ? By the way I'm using google map api v2.

Comment: Finnaly I found the reason : there is another empty surfaceview beneath the webview. It seems that the Mapview image has frozen on that surfaceview. I solved the problem by removing that surfaceview.

Comment: You should share your code and mark your answer as correct answer so that others can find it who otherwise may not read your comment after seeing there is no answer to this question.

Comment: Yes, I'm having the same problem, and I'm not able to solve it. I can find the surfaceview of a mapfragment but not from a MapView...